# S3 PDFs with pre-signed url - can't open in new tab in chrome

Tags: html, amazon-s3

I am trying to open a PDF from S3 using a pre-signed URL. I can download the file using that URL, but when I try to open it in a new tab (using `open(url, '_blank') I get an error screen stating:

> "Failed to load PDF document."

It works great on Safari and on Chrome it works if I try to open the same file from my computer, or use a URL generated from s3 UI.

I tried setting the `content-disposition` header, but to no avail.

This is what my URL looks like:

```
https://our-namespace.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketFolder/fileName.pdf?
AWSAccessKeyId=<accesskey>&Expires=1612918087&Signature=<some-signature>&response
-content-disposition=inline
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do have the same issue. Is there any solution..

Comment: Did you find a solution?